# Does MacBook Pro (2019) screen brightness change when you look at it?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

I was wondering if MacBook Pro automatic brightness adjustment would adjust based on whether you are **looking at it** (also called attention in the iPhone I believe)?

I noticed this when using my MBP in battery mode, it would dim (a lot) when I am not looking at it, and then brighten back up (takes like 1s to increase the brightness in a few stages) when I start looking at it (i don't even have to move the touchpad or hit the keyboard).

Does the ambient light sensor have this functionality?
Or maybe when I look at it my "image" is bright/dark to the ambient light sensor so it changes the brightness accordingly, and correctly in this case?

Comment: Are you shading a light source with your head?

Comment: Nope. The screen brightness changes only with the ambient brightness in the room. If by chance you have unusual eyes which send out an extraordinary amount of photons, then perhaps this would be the result, but that's beyond the realm of the possible, so far as we know.